# Html.BeginForm() works fine, Html.BeginForm("action","controller") ignores [AllowHtmlAttribute]

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, tinymce

I'm using [TinyMCE editor](http://www.tinymce.com/) on admin panel of my site, so i decorate the model properties (target of tinymce) with **[AllowHtml]** and i use **Html.BeginForm()** in views. When i submit form with HTML fields all work fine.

But i have a problem if i use the overload **Html.BeginForm("action","controller")** in the same way, it skips the **[AllowHtml]** and throw the well-know Request.form exception. 
I'm forced to use **[ValidateInput(false)]** on Action-Method to make it work without exception.
Do you know why? Thanks in advance for the clarification,

This is the scenario / **Project**: Asp.net Mvc 4:

**Model / Ricetta.cs**

```
..
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Corpo Articolo vuoto")]
[AllowHtml]
public string corpoTesto { get; set; }
..
```

**Controller / RicetteController.cs**

```
..
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create(RicettaViewModel modelloRicetta)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid) {
..
```

**View Ricette/Create** Called from another Action Method in RicetteController as View("Create", modelObject)

```
 @model WebAPP_MVC4.Areas.Admin.Models.RicettaViewModel
 ...
 @using (Html.BeginForm("Create","Ricette",FormMethod.Post)){
 @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
 @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

....

<fieldset>
    <legend>Corpo Ricetta ~</legend>
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(p=>p.ricetta.corpoTesto)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.TextAreaFor(p=>p.ricetta.corpoTesto, new { @cols = 60, @rows = 20})
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(p=>p.ricetta.corpoTesto)
    </div>
 </fieldset>
..
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I made quick test and everything works perfectly there is no difference in behavior between Html.BeginForm() and Html.BeginForm("action","controller"). Maybe the reason of this issue is in the source code which you didn't show us.

Below my code(works):
VieModel:

```
public class PostViewModel
{
    [AllowHtml]
    [Required]
    public string Content { get; set; } 
}
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View("Create", new PostViewModel());
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create(PostViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return Index();
    }
    return View(model);
}
```

View:

```
@model SendHTmlTpControler.Models.PostViewModel

<html>
<head>
    <script src="~/Scripts/tinymce/tiny_mce.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        tinymce.init({
            selector: "textarea",
            toolbar: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image"
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Create</h2>

    @using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Content)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Content, new { @cols = 60, @rows = 20 })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Content)
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Save" />
        </p>
    }

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. I don't know why, but i had errors for many hours. Now all works, do you think was a firefox cache problem? I changed the settings of TinyMCE from "selector: "textarea"" to "exact: "id". So in the past version of the view all text area field (many of these don't have [Allowhtml] on model)  generate the request.form error (right). After when i set tinymce.init for only textarea field with [allowhtml] on model, the error continue to popup until pc restart (why?). Anyway all works as intended, so thx for your time

Comment: It’s hard to say what was wrong, if caching or some js error then you should use developers tools (e.g. https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/)  if you think that page should work but dosen’t then check in other browser. I had only 2-3 situation in my life when I resolved problem after Visual Studio restart.

Comment: The problem was a TPT hierarchy from "Ricetta model" and its parent "Articolo". Validation attributes aren't shared if you define 2 different METAAttribute class (One METACLass with "Articolo fields shared with "Ricetta", and one METAClass with Ricetta-only-Fields). I know, i'm an idiot :)  // P.s. last tries worked because i forgot [ValidationInput(false)], no jquery bugs. This is my first big web app with asp.net, so i'm not so good. Thanks for you Time Adam :)